# How to test a point is inside diamond-shaped area?

Tags: geometry

I currently creating a isometric game, something with diamond-like shape as a platform

[image: coordinate]

**EDIT 1**
`Ax` and `Ay` on top-center of the diamond, `W` and `H` is width and height of the diamond.
`Px` and `Py` is the coordinate of the point.

**EDIT 2**
the coordinate system is: `x` are greater when on the right, lesser when on the left. `y` are greater when on the top, lesser when on the bottom.

for example a diamond `A(x=10,y=10,w=100,h=60)` with:

- `P(x=10,y=11)` is outside the diamond
- `P(x=10,y=9)` is inside the diamond

How to test if a dot inside that diamond?

Comment: More information is required. How is the diamond and the dot represented? (the image is not clear enough.)

Comment: (width, height, coordinate of the point, coordinate of the topmost point in the diamond?)

Comment: Is this being coded? Also, if $(A_x-H) < p_x < A_x$ and $(A_y-\frac{W}2) < p_y < (A_y+\frac{W}2)$, where the point is represented by $(p_x,p_y)$, then that should tell you if it's in the diamond or not.

Comment: @Kokizzu $|x| + |y| = 1$ is a 'diamond' with centre $(0,0)$, height $2$, and width $2$. Now you can translate or stretch to fit the dimensions in the question.

Comment: i updated the question, add clarification of the variables.

Comment: Use an oblique coordinate system.